‘Status’ in namespace ‘google::protobuf::util’ does not name a type
I am trying out grpc in C++ for an example where my client will send a video and some related json data to a Python grpc server which sends back the video after adding captions and related json data. The server is already available and uses the same proto file (included below), and I am only working on the client code. However, when I am compiling the client code, I am getting the below error.
In file included from /usr/local/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/proto_utils.h:28,
                 from /home/user/grpc_test/cppclient/entity.grpc.pb.h:18,
                 from /home/user/grpc_test/cppclient/entity.grpc.pb.cc:6:
/usr/local/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/config_protobuf.h:91:9: error: ‘Status’ in namespace ‘google::protobuf::util’ does not name a type
   91 | typedef GRPC_CUSTOM_UTIL_STATUS Status;

The contents of the different files used are as follows.
proto file which is stored in protobuf sub-directory in the client directoy.
syntax = "proto3";

package entity;

service Operator {
  rpc Operate (Entity) returns (Entity);
}

message Entity {
  bytes entity = 1;
  bytes options = 2;
}

client.cc
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include "entity.grpc.pb.h"
#include <memory.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <jsoncpp/json/reader.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/value.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/writer.h>

using grpc::Channel;
using grpc::ClientContext;
using grpc::Status;
using entity::Operator;
using entity::Entity;

class EntityClient{
    public:
        EntityClient(std::shared_ptr<Channel> channel) : _stub{Operator::NewStub(channel)} {}

        void Operate(std::string &entity, std::string &options){
            Entity request, response;

            request.set_entity(entity);
            request.set_options(options);

            ClientContext context;

            Status status = _stub->Operate(&context, request, &response);

            //... use the response
        }
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Operator::Stub> _stub;

};

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    std::string server_address{"localhost:50051"};
    EntityClient client{grpc::CreateChannel(server_address, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials())};    

    //Read the video and json and convert to bytes to send to the function

    client.Operate(ent, output);
}

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.17)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project(entity)
add_compile_options(-g -fPIC -std=c++17)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

add_library(entity_protobuf OBJECT
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/protobuf/entity.proto
)
target_link_libraries(entity_protobuf PUBLIC protobuf::libprotobuf)
set(PROTO_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
target_include_directories(entity_protobuf PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROTO_BINARY_DIR}>")
protobuf_generate(
  LANGUAGE cpp
  TARGET entity_protobuf
  IMPORT_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/protobuf"
  PROTOC_OUT_DIR "${PROTO_BINARY_DIR}"
)

protobuf_generate(
    TARGET entity_protobuf
    LANGUAGE grpc
    GENERATE_EXTENSIONS .grpc.pb.h .grpc.pb.cc
    PLUGIN "protoc-gen-grpc=\$<TARGET_FILE:gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin>"
    IMPORT_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/protobuf"
    PROTOC_OUT_DIR "${PROTO_BINARY_DIR}")

include_directories(/usr/include/jsoncpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf)
add_executable(client client.cc)
target_link_libraries(client entity_protobuf jsoncpp protobuf::libprotobuf ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES} ${_REFLECTION} ${_GRPC_GRPCPP} ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF})

server.py
import grpc
from concurrent import futures
import entity_pb2
import entity_pb2_grpc
import cv2
import json

class OperatorServicer(entity_pb2_grpc.OperatorServicer):
    def Operate(self, request, context):
        result = request.entity

        # code for generating the response is here

        return entity_pb2.Entity(entity = ebytes, options = json.dumps(rdict).encode('utf-8'))

def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    entity_pb2_grpc.add_OperatorServicer_to_server(OperatorServicer(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve()


Status is defined by the Abseil library, which is a dependency of gRPC. So you need to include that header, and also include the namespace or add a using declaration.
#include "absl/status/status.h"

using absl::Status;

// or

absl::Status status = ...


The code still gives the same error. From what I understand, this is the google::protobuf::util::Status causing the issue.

Status is indeed coming (transitively) from Abseil. From the line in your compiler output "typedef GRPC_CUSTOM_UTIL_STATUS Status;" you can see in the gRPC source code immediately before this there is an Abseil include. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/b40d919cf2c5b1cef772dbfac09982f6d2804f97/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/config_protobuf.h#L80C1-L84

Thanks for the clarification. However, after including the header and the namespace, the compilation still gives the same error. Any idea why that would happen?
